# render many textures with vbo using JOGL

Tags: jogl

I have many small images, and these images can be combined as a large one.
Now, I use VBO to do this and it's valid. Part of the rendering function is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mListTexData.size(); i++) {
    gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexturesIDs.get(i));
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_QUADS, i*4, 4);
}
```

I wonder if there is a more convenient way to do this.
Thx.

Comment: How many? Are they all the same size? Are they gonna be modified or stay always the same?

Comment: The number is not fixed. Maybe hundreds of images. No, they are not and may be replaced by other images. The vertices should be modified when replaceing images.Thx for reply

Comment: Do you have only a relatively small number of different sizes?

Comment: yes. most of the images are the same size.

Comment: Then you can either use an atlas, one big texture where you have all the small textures inside. You can sub-update it. Or you can use a couple of texture arrays, one for each different size. Or you simple continue to do as you are already doing. Ps: `GL_QUADS` is deprecated, use plain `GL_TRIANGLES`

Comment: Thanks very much. Actually, textures are replaced when selecting different layers of textures. But in one layer, the textures may be not the same size. I'm not familiar with atlas. Does it adapt to this situation?

Comment: I'll write a complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities:

- use an atlas, one big texture where you have all the small textures inside, something like [this](http://www.binpress.com/images/stores/store24122/texture-atlasing-4056.png). You can of course update it, that is overwrite (part of) it. 
  Pro: one unique definitive texture binding
  Cons: had to calculate all the texture coordinates for each sub-image
- you can use a couple of texture arrays, one for each different size. Then you will select the right image with a uniform variable or a vertex attribute. 
  Pro: few texture bindings. 
  Cons: you have to destroy-recreate it if a texture has to be deleted (you may want to create a texture array with an hardcoded length)
- you simple continue to do as you are already doing. 
  Pro: the simplest approach. I strongly suggest you to start like this. Profile, find out if this is a bottleneck and if yes, improve.
  Cons: may be inefficient depending on your situation

Ps: `GL_QUADS` is deprecated, use plain `GL_TRIANGLES`